# How to create a terawallet product_user credit function a hook after successful woocommerce payment

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i'm running a woocommerce wordpress store and i've integrated a virtual wallet add-on called "terawallet aka woo-wallet". this add-on gives each user on the site the option to top-up their virtual wallet, withdraw funds or use it as a payment method during checkout.

i would like to create a function/hook that automatically tops-up the product author wallet(user who posted the product post) when a product is purchased. I'm using a marketplace plugin that sets commission for each vendor/seller and after purchase, admin gets a commision and seller gets the remainder (total_seller_amount)

so e.g
USER 1=seller and user 2=buyer
when buyer purchases a product, the seller virtual account should automatically be topped up with the amount remaining after admin commission when product order is completed(processed). so if the buyer purchases 4 products that belong to 4 different product authors, each author should be credited accordingly to the product linked to their user ID.

the woo-wallet class is called 'woo_wallet_wallet'

below is the function that credits users wallet:

```
    /**
     * Create wallet payment credit transaction
     * @param int $user_id
     * @param float $amount
     * @param string $details
     * @return int transaction id
     */
    public function credit( $user_id = '', $amount = 0, $details = '' ) {
        $this->set_user_id( $user_id );
        return $this->recode_transaction( $amount, 'credit', $details );
    }
```

I tried the following code:

```
$wallet = woo_wallet_wallet ();
$wallet ->credit($product_user_id,, (total_seller_amount), ‘credit’,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
/**
 * Authomatically Top-up Multi vendor Woocommerce Seller on Complete order
 * @param int $order_id
 */
function izzycart_auto_topup_user_on_product_purchase( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    /**
     * You may need order total and customer_id to compose 
     * Transaction message for top, which is why it is added
     * below as optional (if needed)
    */
    $total = $order->get_total(); // <=== Total order Price (if needed)
    $customer_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // <=== Customer ID (if needed)
    $order_items = $order->get_items(); // <=== Grab all items in order

    $item_details = [];

    foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {
        // Get the ID of each item in Order
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $item_details[] = [
            'product_name'  => $item->get_name(),
            'total'         => $item->get_total(),
            'author'        => get_post($product_id)->post_author // <=== The product/item author ID
        ];
    }

    //Loop through all product/items author and add topup their wallet
    foreach ($item_details as $item_detail) {
        $wallet = new Woo_Wallet_Wallet();

        // Get Administrator's percentage
        $adminsCut = 0.2 * $item_detail['total']; // <=== Admin Takes 20%

        // Get Author's Percentage
        $authorsCut = $item_detail['total'] - (0.2 * $item_detail['total']); // <=== Author Takes 80%

        //Top-Up Admin
        if( $item_detail['author'] != 1 ) {
             /**
             * By Default Administrator has an ID of 1
             * if Author of product is not Admin
            */
            $topUpAdmin = $wallet->credit(1, $adminsCut, "Top-Up cut from {$item_detail['product_name']} sales");

            //Top-Up Author of Product
            $topUpAuthor = $wallet->credit($item_detail['author'], $authorsCut, "Top-Up from {$item_detail['product_name']} purchase");
    }else {
            // Author of product is Admin. Give admin all the money
            $topUpAdmin = $wallet->credit(1, $item_detail['total'], "Top-Up from {$item_detail['product_name']} sales");
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'izzycart_auto_topup_user_on_product_purchase', 10, 1 );
```

TESTED AND WORKING

Admin Top-up Transaction screenshot
[image]

Author of product Top-up Transaction screenshot
[image]

WC Version: v4.5.2 
Wordpress Version: v5.5.1 
TeraWallet Version: v1.3.16

This code should go in your theme's function.php file